# Upload files to ftp server using cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, ftp, ftp-server

Is there anyway to upload files to an ftp server using cakephp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well ultimately you'll be using *php* :p

Here's a cake component to get you started: http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/31521

and of course the old fashioned way: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Answer (score 4):

There's a pretty solid plugin that will help out: [CakeFTP](https://github.com/shama/cakeftp)

Answer (score -4):

u cane use FTP with cakebin

http://blog.w3web.in/blog/cake-bin-with-ftp

Comment: this link is invalid and irrelevant